# Tabular Format not visible in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science, anaconda3

[The current Image of the csv file when I use panda to read it]

I was compelled to delete a few files from the Anaconda folder in my laptop and now when I used anaconda Jupyter notebook to work on a ML problem and used panda to display and read the csv file I see this(as per the image.  :::  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUJxh.png) type of a view, instead of the fine looking tabular format .  Can someone please suggest me an idea to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

just write `data.head()` instead of `print data.head()`

Comment: I did use print(data.head()) but it appeared the same

Comment: Check out this comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208446/13656812

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

[image: CODE SCREENSHOT]
This should probably solve the error or doubts.